# Detecting a completion of async block of code - swift 4

Tags: swift, escaping, closures, sequence

I am trying to check if a data exists in the database. The fetching of the data is done in an asynchronous method. I need to detect when the function finishes and execute the next sequence of code.

This is the source code.

```
  func doesDmExist(recipientId: String, completion:@escaping (Bool) -> Void) -> Void{
    // get all the direct message rooms of the current user.
    Api.User_Chat.observeUserDirectMessage(withId: CurrentUserInfo.uid) { (dm) in
        // check if direct message exists with the given recipient id
        Api.Chat_Group.directMessageExists(chatroomId: dm, recipientId: (recipientId), completion: { (exists) in
            if(exists){
                self.dmExists = exists
                // complete.
                completion(exists)
            }
        })
    }
    // whatever I put on this line will get executed before above code is finished.
}
```

Since the fetching of the data is done in asynchronous manner, I cannot create a completion statement at the end of the function (it will simply execute the completion statement before the above code is executed). 
Although I am able to successfully detect if the data exists or not, this is not really useful. I execute the next logic of code based on the value of variable "dmExists," but the next logic of code often executes before the updating of the value "dmExists." I can't really think of a smart solution for this. Any suggestions?

This is how i call the function

```
 if let id = cell.user?.uid {
    doesDmExist(recipientId: id) { (flag) in
        if self.dmExists {
            print("exists")
        }else{
            print("nope")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the else clause never gets executed. "false" value is never escaped from the function. If I try to move the if statement outside of the escape closure, it executes the if statement before the function completes.

Comment: what database library are you using?

Comment: Show how you call `doesDmExist`.

Comment: Use the `completion` closure - although it really should be getting called even when `exists` is `false`

Comment: I am using Firebase

Answer (score 0):

First, update your posted code to call `completion` no matter what value you get for `exists`.

```
func doesDmExist(recipientId: String, completion:@escaping (Bool) -> Void) -> Void{
    // get all the direct message rooms of the current user.
    Api.User_Chat.observeUserDirectMessage(withId: CurrentUserInfo.uid) { (dm) in
        // check if direct message exists with the given recipient id
        Api.Chat_Group.directMessageExists(chatroomId: dm, recipientId: (recipientId), completion: { (exists) in
            self.dmExists = exists
            completion(exists)
        })
    }
}
```

That's all you need to do there.

Then your call needs to be something like:

```
doesDmExist(recipientId: someId) { (exists) in
    // process the result as needed
}
```

Comment: since I only escape (true) when the data exists, the else clause in the completion block is never executed. If I try to move the if statement outside of the completion blocked. It is executed before the completion of the function.

Comment: The only code you need to change is to get rid of `if (exists)` where you call `completion(exists)`. Leave everything else the same.